# Where to test for this condition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to test for when the player's body moves past a certain point on the screen, and call the gameOver node when they do.

I tried putting it in the touches began method but then every time the user touched after that it would continue to add gameOver nodes.

I also tried putting it in the `-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` method but it added a gameOver node every frame.

This is the code that tests when the user is out of moves/crosses a certain point on the screen:

```
//Check to see if moves are at 0.
if (movesRemaining < 0) {
    movesRemaining = 0;
}

if (_fish.position.y < CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-160) {
    movesRemaining = 0;
}

if (movesRemaining == 0) {
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                         [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5],
                                         [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [self outOfMoves];

    }],
                                         ]]];
}
```

Which calls this:

```
-(void)outOfMoves {

    SKShapeNode *gameOverNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    [gameOverNode setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-140, -125, 280, 250), 10, 10, nil)];
    gameOverNode.strokeColor = gameOverNode.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:192/255. green:47/255. blue:47/255. alpha:1.0];
    gameOverNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), -150);

    SKLabelNode *outOfMoves = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Condensed"];
    outOfMoves.position = CGPointMake(0,80);
    outOfMoves.fontSize = 40;
    outOfMoves.text = @"OUT OF MOVES";

    SKLabelNode *reTry = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Condensed"];
    reTry.position = CGPointMake(0, 30);
    reTry.fontSize = 40;
    reTry.fontColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255. green:156/255. blue:0/255. alpha:1.0];
    reTry.name = @"reTry";
    reTry.text = @"TRY AGAIN";

    [gameOverNode addChild:outOfMoves];
    [gameOverNode addChild:reTry];
    [self addChild:gameOverNode];

    [gameOverNode runAction:[SKAction moveToY:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+40 duration:0.5]];

}
```

**Where is the best place to put the condition of checking where on the screen the user is / when they are at 0 lives in a sprite-kit code?**

It accurately tested when it was updated with frames, but added too many.

I also tried using a "performSelector" call inside the didMoveToView method but that didn't work either..

(code:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkNow) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

)

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, `-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` is a good place to put that check. However, your game over nodes are being created multiple times because the check repeats multiple times while the `outOfMoves` method is still running.

I suggest you add a `BOOL` variable that is originally `NO` and changed to `YES` when the `outOfMoves` method is called. Then back in your `update:`, check that this variable is `NO` before calling `outOfMoves` again. That way you won't keep calling the method while it's running. Also, you can set this variable back to `NO` when your method is completed and you're ready again.